# Why is it recommeneded to install via bower or npm?

Tags: npm, bower, bower-install

This might be a stupid question but I believe I should know this since I am just starting out in the web development field rather than just assuming. I normally see this

> Install via npm or bower (recommended) or manually download the package

or something of that sorts. My Assumption is that the node_module and bower_component updates the packages automatically, however I am not sure.

Sometimes I install with npm or bower, or sometimes I just mannually download the package to which I have seen no difference. Could someone please tell me why it is important to install via npm or bower so I can know for sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package managers allow you to keep third party code separate from your code and have consistent versions of that code. With npm or bower you can set out exactly what dependencies you project has, and what versions through a single file, without having to bloat your codebase with the dependencies themselves.

This means that anyone who wants to set up the project can just download the core code and run `npm install` or the equivalent command, and install all the dependencies at the latest supported version.